# Init object from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to init an object from JSON; like this:

```
function myObj(myJSON) {
    this = JSON.parse(myJSON);
}

var test = new myObj('{"name":"test"}');
```

But since you cannot set 'this', the above code gives this error:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

I thought about creating a temporary object and trying to copy it like so:

```
function myObj(myJSON) {
    var tempObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    this.name = tempObj.name;
    // do the same for all other properties
}

var test = new myObj('{"name":"test"}');
```

Which works, but ideally I'd prefer not to have to copy each property of the object one by one. So I looked up ways to copy objects in JavaScript and none of them work for my circumstance since they all require direct setting of 'this'.

```
function myObj(myJSON) {
    var tempObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    this = tempObj.splice(0);
}

var test = new myObj('{"name":"test"}');
```

UPDATE: I cannot just "cut to the chase? var test=JSON.parse('{"name":"test"}');" because my object will have additional types, such as:

```
function myObj(myJSON) {
    this = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    this.propertyNotFromJSON = 5;
    this.func = function() {
        this.propertyNotFromJSON++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Drop the 'new' operator and just return the result of `JSON.parse()`? Or perhaps wrap all your results in a new object and just return that object.

Comment: Why not just `JSON.parse(...)`? This parses your JSON into a JavaScript object.

Comment: Isn't the return value from `JSON.parse()` itself exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: @War10ck but it would not have the right __prototype

Comment: Why not just cut to the chase? `var test=JSON.parse('{"name":"test"}');`

Comment: So basically you're trying to return a new instance of an object literal with a Function prototype ?

Comment: @tucuxi It doesn't appear that the OP is using the `__prototype` in any particular way. This shouldn't be a problem if the above is the actual code snippet and not a subset of the OP's code.

Comment: @adeneo that sounds like the Crockford method to me...

Comment: @13ruce1337 - Yeah, he's probably the only one disillusioned enough to think that would be a good idea, or even possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myObj(myJSON) {
    var tempObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    for(var prop in tempObj) this[prop] = tempObj[prop]; // copy all properties from the JSON
    this.propertyNotFromJSON = 5;
    this.func = function() {
        this.propertyNotFromJSON++;
    }
}

var test = new myObj('{"name":"test"}');
```

This does what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could automatically copy each property one by one by:

```
var temp = JSON.parse(myJSON);

for(prop in temp) {
 this[prop] = temp[prop];
}
```

Comment: I found about this and posted it just before you answered.